# Word VBA hide macro from macro list

Tags: vba, ms-word

I know you can use

```
Option Private Module
```

to hide macros from the macro list, but apparently this is not true for public functions in class modules that do not have an input parameter. Any ideas how I could hide them?
This is the public procedure in my class

[image]

Its appearing in the macro list:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to remain `Public`, you can pass to it an optional argument and do nothing with it, so it doesn't show up in the Macro list.

```
Public Sub RemoveDuplicates(Optional DoNothing As Variant)

  'Macro code goes here

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Private` and not `Public` like:

```
Private Sub RemoveDuplicates()
' your code here
End Sub
```

[Option Private](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266185(v=vs.60).aspx) only restrict inter-project visibility as explained in the link.
It does not hide it in the *Macro List*.